# Does Jasmine have an after-advice spy?

Tags: jasmine, aop

When spying on a method, we can either callThrough (use original implementation) or callFake (use a custom implementation).

What I want is a behaviour similar to callThrough but inspect/modify its return value before returning it to the caller.

So I can do something like this:

```
spyOn(foo, "fetch").and.afterCall(function(result) {
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    result.bar = "baz";
    return result;
});
```

Right now the simplest way is doing something like this:

```
var original = foo.fetch;
foo.fetch = function() {
    var result = original.apply(this, arguments);
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    result.bar = "baz";
    return result;
}
```

Which is somewhat annoying because now I have to manually restore the spy instead of having the framework automatically does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Jasmine have an after-advice spy?

**Generally: no.**

You could extend the [`SpyStrategy` object](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.5.0/src/core/SpyStrategy.js) with such a function though:

```
this.callThroughAndModify = function(resultModifier) {
  var result;

  plan = function() {
    result = originalFn.apply(this, arguments);
    return resultModifier(result);
  };

  return getSpy();
};
```

You've to clone the above `SpyStrategy` file and insert that method.

Usage:

```
var obj = {
    fn: function(a) { return a * 2; }
};

spyOn(obj, "fn").and.callThroughAndModify(function(result) {
    console.log("Original result: ", result);
    return 1;
});

expect(obj.fn(2)).toBe(1);
```

Drawbacks:

- You've to replace the whole SpyStrategy.js
- You've to load that script before Jasmine [initializes the original SpyStrategy at boot](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.5.0/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js#L40)